# Error setting up multiple vhosts with Apache2 on Mint 15

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, vhosts, linux-mint

I just installed Apache2 on mint 15. I am able to see the localhost and so decided to add virtual hosts for my projects.

1. I have added the hostnames at /etc/hosts

   127.0.0.1   eclipse
2. I also added vhost details at /etc/apache2/site-avaliable:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@eclipse
   ServerName eclipse
   ServerAlias www.eclipse

   # Indexes+Document Root
   DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
   DocumentRoot /home/cygnus/Dropbox/Workspace_Eclipse

   #logfiles
   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/eclipse-error.log
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/eclipse-access.log combined

   <Directory /home/cygnus/Dropbox/Workspace_Eclipse>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride all
       Order Deny,Allow
       Deny from all
       Allow from 127.0.0.1
   </Directory>
   <IfModule dir_module>
       DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
   </IfModule>

   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. I  activated the vhost using:

   ```
   sudo a2ensite example.com
   ```
4. Also added following to /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

   ```
   ServerName localhost
   ServerName eclipse
   ```

After all the work I checked:

```
    http://localhost - works OK.
    http://eclipse - gives 403 error.
```

Do I need to do anything more to add vhost in linux? Did I miss or mess up some step?
Any help is appreciated - Thanks in advance :)

Update:
I tried changing the DocumentRoot to "/var/www/test/" - this works
but I need it to work at home level.

I used chown and chgrp to set owner and group to both www-data and root - neither worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer [here](http://shriikant.blogspot.com/2011/03/permission-denied-htaccess-pcfgopenfile.html)

All I was missing was: chmod  -R 755 /home/cygnus/Dropbox/*

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the `<Directory>` container:

```
<Directory /home/cygnus/Dropbox/Workspace_Eclipse>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

Are you *sure* your requests are actually coming from `127.0.0.1`? What's the remote_addr IP that shows up in the logs? To verify, try removing the `Deny from all` line and see if you can access it.

Comment: I am getting this log: [Sun Sep 08 23:48:48 2013] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /home/cygnus/Dropbox/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable ... request is comming from 127.0.0.1. I also just now tried removing everything below DocumentRoot - still same error